# ASP.NET MVC3: Do I need to use a MembershipProvider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, multi-tenant

I am building a multi-tenant site with MVC3. Prior to this project I had never touched either the .NET stack or web development in general, so as you can imagine my domain knowledge is somewhat lacking.

I'm still using the default AccountController architecture, but I pretty quickly determined that I didn't want to use aspnetdb.mdf for authentication, as its design is pretty different from my requirements. I do want role-based authentication, so I ultimately wrote custom User and Role classes as code-first Entity classes and used [this tutorial](http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx) to set up a custom MembershipProvider and RoleProvider.

Everything works fine at the moment, but as I'm building the multi-tenancy functionality it's getting messier. Based on [this example](http://lukesampson.com/post/303245177/subdomains-for-a-single-application-with-asp-net-mvc), I am using a custom extension of Controller which keeps track of which tenant is using this session, and all my controllers extend this class instead of the base Controller class.

All tenants are using the same database. Each entity has a Tenant property that identifies who it belongs to.

**So, here's the problem:**
Usernames do not need to be globally unique. Only the combination of username and tenant must be unique. Thus, ValidateUser needs to know the username, password, *and tenant*. Since my custom MembershipProvider is not a Controller, it doesn't know which tenant is using the session, and the ValidateUser method only accepts username and password so I can't pass it that information.

Furthermore, pretty much everything MembershipProvider does besides ValidateUser is already implemented in a UserRepository class, which that tutorial told me to make. I'm rather fond of the Repository pattern, and it's way more convenient than adhering to MembershipProvider's interface, but now there's a massive conflict of interest between UserRepository and MembershipProvider.

**So, my question:**
Do I need to use MembershipProvider, or even Membership, at all?
It seems like everything MembershipProvider does would be performed more conveniently by my repository class. At this point all I'd have to do is write a new Authorize attribute that doesn't rely on Membership, and everything should work without any MembershipProvider at all, right? If I don't drop Membership I'm forced to completely mutilate my MembershipProvider implementation to the point that it barely resembles the original interface anyway.

...Either that or Membership does a ton of things I'm unaware of and removing it is blatant stupidity. That is also a distinct possibility.

Comment: Aside of using or not membership, I suggest you use email as user name... and if that email works for 2 tenants... once logged you could choose the tenant (may be displaying business logo if each tenant a business entiyt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the membership provider at all. Its simply provided as a quick and consistent way to get up and running. Some choose it because it supports multiple databases (universal membership providers include azure as well as sql ce, express, and full) but for others trying to map it to your applications rules can be more difficult than the <5 lines of code it takes to authenticate and issue your own forms auth ticket.

With that said I'm assuming you are using forms authentication. You can simply issue the ticket yourself. I would still program against an interface for this which the default MVC template should have, so simply add in a new tenant id.

With that said, I'd consider having unique names. It ensures you don't 'forget' to do an additional tenant check somewhere else in the app and tenant1\userBip and tenant2\userBip surprisingly end up stomping on each others record at some point.

True, testing should uncover this - if testing is complete : )

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm already issuing the forms authentication ticket myself anyway (the default AccountController does, and I haven't changed it much). I've started proceeding forward without using MembershipProvider and everything is working fine so far. Also, good point about the usernames. At the moment I'm using a highly robust testing suite, consisting of me clicking things and seeing if the app breaks.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need to use Membership, but consider for a moment exactly what Membership is.  Membership does not involve your users names, or addresses, or other information.  Membership is strictly related to the login account of the system.  It only handles details with creating, validating, updating, or deleting the information needed to login.  That's it.

Likewise, the Role system is only assigning a role name to the user.

Ultimately, Membership and Roles are just implementations of the IPrincipal interface.  While FormsAuthentication is an implementation of the IIdentity interface.  These work together so that you can utlize the built-in ASP.NET Authorization and Authentication system.

Membership actually does have the concept of multiple tennants.  This functionality is accomplished via the "ApplicationNane" field of the aspnet_users table (also settable in the Membership class itself)

From the documentation on the Membership class:

> The ApplicationName is used to identify users specific to an application. That is, the same user name can exist in the database for multiple ASP.NET applications that specify a different ApplicationName. This enables multiple applications to use the same database to store user information without running into duplicate user name conflicts. Alternatively, multiple ASP.NET applications can use the same user database by specifying the same ApplicationName. The ApplicationName can be set programmatically or declaratively in the configuration for the Web application.

Now, this is designed to typically be set in the Web.Config and stay the same for the life of the app, but I see no reason why you can't use it to specify which tennant you want.

The only issue here is that Membership.ApplicationName is static, which means it's shared by all threads running in the App Pool.  However, if you use some kind of lock around accessing it, then this shouldn't be a huge issue (though it could affect scalability at some level).

This would basically allow you to use the standard, out of the box membership provider without any changes.  You just have ot make sure to guard the access calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hadn't thought to look up what ApplicationName is for.